# Controlling python script with CSV

Tags: python, csv, variables

I want to control my python script output with values in a csv:
I select a Category and some parameters like that:
[csv1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3bMt.png)
or like that [csv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8jbt.png)

In my python-script I got the Values of each parameter in a list that looks like that:

```
A_Names = ("Anton", "Berta", "Charlie")
Ages = ("32","18","23")
Nicknames = ("Agent A", "Agent B", None)
Birthdays = ("03.03.1986", "02.02.2000", "01.01.1995")
IDs = (100, 200, 300)
```

The idea now is to have a script that will combine these information so the output for [csv1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3bMt.png) would be:

```
Anton
   A_Name: Anton
   Age: 32
   Nickname: Agent A
   Birthday: 03.03.1986
Berta
   A_Name: Berta
   Age: 18
   Nickname: Agent B
   Birthday: 02.02.2000
Charlie
   A_Name: Charlie
   Age: 23
   Nickname: No Nickname yet
   Birthday: 01.01.1995
```

and the output for the [csv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8jbt.png) would be:

```
Anton
   Nickname: Agent A
   A_Name: Anton
   ID: 100
Berta
   Nickname: Agent B
   A_Name: Berta
   ID: 200
Charlie
   Nickname: No Nickname yet
   A_Name: Charlie
   ID: 300
```

and of course it should also work both together in a [csv3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os46P.png) like that, and the same outputs just after another.

So the first idea was just to code my output like that:

```
#let's assume i got the columns from the csv in lists like that:
Categories = ("Agents", "Agents")
Parameter1 = ("A_Name", "Nickname")
Parameter2 = ("Age", "A_Name")
Parameter3 = ("Nickname", "ID")
Parameter4 = ("Birthday")

#then the most unflexible code would look like that:

def Show_Values():
    for n in range (0,len(A_Names)):
        print A_Names[n]
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter1[0], A_Names[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter2[0], Ages[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter3[0], Nicknames[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter4[0], Birthdays[n])

    for n in range (0,len(A_Names)):
        print A_Names[n]
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter1[1], Nicknames[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter2[1], A_Names[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (Parameter3[1], IDs[n])

Show_Values()
```

So this is very stupid code and I repeat myself there over and over and always need to add the correct value for the 2nd `%s`.
My question now is how can I create a smarter, shorter Code, that knows that A_Name[0] is the first Element of A_Names.
And that he should add the "`%s`: `%s`" % (parameter, value), automatically for the amount of parameters I am looking for via the csv. I think I need
the length of the row for that so two more lists from the csv:

```
Row0 = (Agents, A_Name, Age, Nickname, Birthday)
Row1 = (Agents, Nickname, A_Name, ID)
len(Row0)-1
len(Row1)-1
```

---

edit:

Ok thank you so far, here's my new approach, reading rows only from a csv:

```
import csv

with open("TableAgentsComma.csv", "rb") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    inputHeader = next(reader)
    rows=[r for r in reader]


A_Names = ["Anton", "Berta", "Charlie"]
Ages = ["32","18","23"]
Nicknames = ["Agent A", "Agent B", None]
Birthdays = ["03.03.1986", "02.02.2000", "01.01.1995"]
IDs = [100, 200, 300]

def Show_Values():
    for n in range (0, len(A_Names)):
        print A_Names[n]
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[0][1], A_Names[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[0][2], Ages[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[0][3], Nicknames[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[0][4], Birthdays[n])
    for n in range (0, len(A_Names)):
        print A_Names[n]
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[1][1], Nicknames[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[1][2], A_Names[n])
        print "  %s: %s" % (rows[1][3], IDs[n])

Show_Values()
```

But of course it's still an inflexible script and I would like it to respond to the csv, and generate its output depending on the amount of rows and the parameters inside.
Also I need to find out how the script will know that the parameter "ID" is found in the list IDs etc.

The csv file:

```
Category,Parameter1,Parameter2,Parameter3,Parameter4,Parameter5,
Agents,A_Name,Age,Nickname,Birthday,,
Agents,Nickname,A_Name,ID,,,
Agents,A_Name,Age,,,,
Agents,ID,,,,,
```

Comment: Have you looked into `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: my main focus is not yet on reading from the csv yet, i know that this works... so i just assumed that i already got the Rows and Columns in lists as shown. my main problem is how to make a smarter code out of that.

Comment: Reading the CSV will produce a list or dictionary for each row, not each column as you are using, so you probably really should look first at the CSV reading because if you don't you are forcing yourself to later have to spend time/effort to adapt the CSV reader output into a different format for this style of processing.

Comment: barny is correct. In addition to that, you have to option to use `csv.DictReader`, which will return each row as `{column1: value1, column2: value2, ...}`, so what you want to do becomes much easier.

Comment: okay, thank you so far. I edited my post and added a new approach... still same question but now a little more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the data as a dictionary you can look up the key based on the name in the `csv` file:

```
data = {
    "A_Names" : ["Anton", "Berta", "Charlie"],
    "Ages" : ["32","18","23"],
    "Nicknames":  ["Agent A", "Agent B", None],
    "Birthdays": ["03.03.1986", "02.02.2000", "01.01.1995"],
    "IDs": [100, 200, 300]
}

def Show_Values():
    for row in rows:
        for n in range (0, len(data["A_Names"])):
            print data["A_Names"][n]
            for header in row:
                if header == "Agents" or header == "": # This field doesn't match any thing in the data.
                    continue
                header = header.strip()
                header += "s"
                print "  %s: %s" % (header, data[header][n])
```

Since the data is now in a `dict` we can look up the value based on the parameter which we got from the file. I probably should have called it "parameter" rather than "header".

```
Show_Values()
```

Output:

```
Anton
  A_Names: Anton
  Ages: 32
  Nicknames: Agent A
  Birthdays: 03.03.1986
Berta
  A_Names: Berta
  Ages: 18
  Nicknames: Agent B
  Birthdays: 02.02.2000
Charlie
  A_Names: Charlie
  Ages: 23
  Nicknames: None
  Birthdays: 01.01.1995
```

And then from the second row in the `.csv`:

```
Anton
  Nicknames: Agent A
  A_Names: Anton
  IDs: 100
Berta
  Nicknames: Agent B
  A_Names: Berta
  IDs: 200
Charlie
  Nicknames: None
  A_Names: Charlie
  IDs: 300
```

Comment: when i execute the code i get a Key Error: 's'. The whole output looks like that:Traceback (most recent call last):
Anton
  File "/Users/xx/PycharmProjects/CreatePython2/venv/NamesDict.py", line 27, in <module>
  A_Names: Anton
    Show_Values()
  Ages: 32
  File "/Users/xx/PycharmProjects/CreatePython2/venv/NamesDict.py", line 25, in Show_Values
  Nicknames: Agent A
    print "  %s: %s" % (parameter, data[parameter][n])
  Birthdays: 03.03.1986
KeyError: 's'

Comment: Add in an if statement that checks if header is an empty sting. I add "s" to get the plural but you must be reading in something empty

Comment: Either that or provide the text of the csv rather than the image and I can check further

Comment: i edited the csv file in my first post. I understand why you added the "s" and it makes perfect sense

Comment: I tried the if statement with an empty string and this works, yay thank you so very much. But can you please explain why i must reading in something empty?

Comment: In your csv, you had a bunch of `,,,,` in a row. All those are empty cells so the program needs to know how to handle it. If this works, please upvote and/or accept the answer.  Let me know if you have any other questions.